# Why does my profile on Expatriates.SE sort before my profile on Stack Overflow on google?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

I have never posted a question or answer on Expatriates.SE, but have been very active on Stack Overflow in the past, yet when I search for my name in Google Expatriates.SE comes much higher in the result then Stack Overflow.

As every posting I have made on SE, has my name as a link back to my profile on SE, there must be someone being done to the links or sitemap files by the SE engine to point Google in the wrong direction.

It may something daft like I have enough rep on Stack overflow that the links on my profile page don’t get a “no follow”, but the links on all the other profile pages do get a “no flower”.      Profile pages all link to each other.

(I do not wish to have to put a false name on all my profiles apart from Stack Overflow just so google gets it right, or even delete all account apart from Stack Overflow.)

Comment: In this particular case, you could just delete the ExPats profile, since you have no posts. But I agree, it's still weird search engine behavior.

Comment: @Emrakul next month it will be a different SE site, maybe one that I have asked 1 or 2 questions on.

Comment: Oh, weird, nevermind then. I thought it was localized.

Comment: You can edit your profile (there's an option to copy it to all sites) and state that you're most active on SO (and provide a link to visit your SO profile).

Comment: Do you visit that site a lot, to view questions and answers, etc? That might be a localized result for you only (Google trying to suggest things that might be more interesting). When I search your name (just "Ian Ringrose" is what you're searching, I presume), I get your Stack overflow profile as the number one result. Your Expatriates profile is seventh in the list.

Comment: @animuson, I have tried using "in private browsing" and get the same results, so it is not a google cookee controlling it, it may be IP address, or that we hit different data center with a different version of the google software running due to location.

Comment: To check that Google doesn't use your IP to modify the search results, you can try the DuckDuckGo search engine which use Google anonymously (if I remember correctly).